# Custom Format decimal number as N Week N Day

Tags: excel-formula, custom-formatting

I have a table of dates that i reference in another table that shows the number of weeks & days elapsed since TODAY().I use the DOLLARFR() function to get a decimal value that represents the weeks & days elapsed.

```
=DOLLARFR((TODAY()-M8)/7,7)
```

Where M8 = "22-Dec-2017" & TODAY() = "29-Dec-2017". This gives me a decimal number 1.1, where integer part 1 represents a Week & the decimal part 1 represents a Day.

Since i plan to find the Minimum & Maximum Week-Day values of each row in this table, i want to use a Custom Format to only format the display. The Custom format should show the value as 1W 1D.

The best i could do is:

```
#0"W" .0#"D";;#0"W" .0#"D";
```

But it shows the decimal point in the format:

```
A         B         C         D
1W .1D    0W .3D    0W .6D    2W .3D
```

Does anyone know how to create such a Custom format in Excel?

Comment: `=INT(DOLLARFR((TODAY()-M8)/7,7)) & "W" & " " & ROUND(MOD(DOLLARFR((TODAY()-M8)/7,7),1)*10,0) & "D"` without the formatting.

Comment: Thanks Scott. But this is what i dont want to do, as this would turn the value into a textual value and not a number. I want to find MIN & MAX of each row. So i need a numeric value that would only look like "nW nD" for display, but still be numeric internally. Hope you are getting my point!

Comment: The problem is the Custom formatting is not that flexible.  So either you forgo the formatting or you add helper cells that hold the number to which you refer in your later formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

```
#0"W". 0#"D";;#0"W". 0#"D";
```

which is more palatable:

```
A         B         C         D
1W. 1D    0W. 3D    0W. 6D    2W. 3D
```